# Listing S3 bucket objects with specific storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

It's very time consuming to get objects from Glacier so I decided to use S3 IA storage class instead.
I need to list all the objects in my bucket that have Glacier storage class  (I configured it via LifeCycle policy) and to change it to S3 IA.

Is there any script or a tool for that?

Comment: any idea how to achieve it with javascript , using aws-sdk

Answer (score 18):

You can do that using [list-objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html)

`list-objects` will return the `StorageClass`, in your case you want to filter for values where it is `GLACIER`

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket %bucket_name% --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`GLACIER`]'
```

What you want then is to get only the list of Key that matches

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket %bucket_name% --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`GLACIER`][Key]' --output text
```

Then you will need to copy the object with changing the storage class of the Key

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket %bucket_name% --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`GLACIER`][Key]' --output text
| xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/{} s3://bucket_name/{} --storage-class STANDARD_IA
```

Answer (score 1):

and ... if you need to run this from Powershell in windows, I had to do this:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket Your_Bucket --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`STANDARD`][Key]' --output text | foreach { aws s3 cp s3://Your_Bucket/$_ s3://Your_Bucket/$_ --storage-class REDUCED_REDUNDANCY }
```