# Running queries against Amazon S3 using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Because of [Glacier Deep's expensive support](https://therub.org/2015/11/18/glacier-costlier-than-s3-for-small-files/) for small objects, I am writing an archiver.  It would be most helpful to me to be able to ask `boto3` to give me a list of objects in the bucket which are not already in the desired storage class.  Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242508/6796731), I know I can do this in a shell:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKETNAME --query 'Contents[?StorageClass!=`DEEP_ARCHIVE`]'
```

Is there a way to pass that `query` parameter into `boto3`?  I haven't dug into the source yet, but I thought it was essentially a wrapper on the command line tools- but I can't find docs or examples anywhere using this technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass that query parameter into boto3?

Sadly, you can't do this, as `--query` option is **specific** to AWS CLI. But boto3 is Python AWS SDK, so you very easily post-process its outputs to obtain the same results as from CLI.

The `--query` option is based on [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/). So if you really want to use `jmespath` in your python, you can use [jmespath package](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) .

Comment: so what you're saying is that in fact, the `aws` command above is pulling back JSON for all the objects rather than doing an intelligent query, and it's being post-processed by the CLI tool?

Comment: @Frank Yes, exactly. You can do the same using `jq` to post-process AWS CLI output, instead of using `--query`.

Comment: That's hugely helpful- if there's no intelligent filtering at the head end, then I'll just do whatever processing I want myself.  Did you find that out by digging through source, or is this buried in documentation somewhere that I missed?  How do I get to your level of familiarity?

Comment: Thanks. Its also stated in docs ([Client-side filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side)) that query is client side only. I also learn as I go. By browsing SO I often learn something new about AWS:-)

Answer (score 2):

Query S3 Inventory size column with Athena.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory-athena-query.html

Since July 2022 S3 Lifecycles have an [Object Size filter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/optimize-storage-costs-with-new-amazon-s3-lifecycle-filters-and-actions/).